# Join two Lists<strings> to create a List of KeyValuePair

Tags: c#

I've got a list of `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`

```
var results = new List <KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

I've also got two Lists of strings:

```
var position= new List<string>{ "first", "second", "third" };
 
var name = new List<string>{ "John", "Diana", "Matthew", "Lisa", "James"};
```

The two lists can be of a different size, just would add an empty string instead.

I want to merge them together to create a new `results`. I'm currently using this:

```
 results = position.Zip(name, (x, y) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x, y)).ToList();
```

This would work if only both lists are of the same size. However, if not, its trimming the `name` list to match the `position` list. So not all values are there.

I need to achieve the following

```
first,John
second,Diana
third, Matthew
     , Lisa
     , Jame
```

**Both lists can be, at any time, of variable sizes, not fixed. So sometimes `name` can be greater than `position` and vice versa.**

I've seen were `SelectMany` is used, but not sure how to combine it to my `Zip`.
Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: When you say "The two lists can be of a different size", can either be longer or just `name` longer than `position`?

Comment: Yes that is correct, both lists can be, at any time, of variable sizes. Not fixed. So sometimes `name` can be greater than `position` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I would increase the length of the name list to match the number of elements in position, adding empty strings as needed.

```
position.Zip(name.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, Math.Max(0, position.Count - name.Count))), (x, y) => ...
```

Comment: in the subtraction would there be a resutl of -1? If so would that affect? Because both lists can be of variable sizes, they are not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways of doing this. For example, a DIY one liner would be:

```
var position = // positions here
var name = // names here

var results = name
    .Select((n, nIdx) => new KeyValuePair(nIdx >= position.Length ? null : position[nIdx], n))
    .Concat(position.Skip(name.Length).Select(p => new KeyValuePair(p, (string)null))))
    .ToList();
```

Edited to allow either list to be larger.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that `name` has more elements than `position`?

Comment: Or the same number, yes.

Comment: OP confirmed my suspicious that `position` can also have more elements than `name`

Comment: Easily taken care of, edited my answer accordingly!

Comment: @Blindy there is an issue with KeyValuePair (it takes two arguments). Compiler not happy about it?